# How to get a simple cvs log, sorted by date?

Tags: cvs

I checked out http://xmltv.cvs.sourceforge.net/xmltv, and I wanted to see a quick log of the project, hopefully something like `git log` outputs.

But when I issue `csv log | less`, I get an extremely verbose output like;

```
RCS file: /cvsroot/xmltv/xmltv/.cvsignore,v
Working file: .cvsignore
head: 1.5
branch:
locks: strict
access list:
symbolic names:
        V0_5_66: 1.5
        V0_5_65: 1.5
        V0_5_64: 1.5
        V0_5_63: 1.5
        V0_5_62: 1.5
        V0_5_61: 1.3
        V0_5_60: 1.3
        V0_5_59: 1.2
        V0_5_58: 1.1
keyword substitution: kv
total revisions: 5;     selected revisions: 5
description:
----------------------------
revision 1.5
date: 2012/03/18 16:26:50;  author: knowledgejunkie;  state: Exp;  lines: +5 -1
Ignore git/mercurial files for any developers using these locally
.....
```

... and I cannot tell if this is the latest commit, or what is it.

The closest I got to is `cvs history -a  | less`:

```
O 2012-01-02 03:46 +0000 alewando        xmltv                                  =xmltv=                                  <remote>/*
O 2003-07-15 11:03 +0000 allena28        xmltv                                  =xmltv=                                  <remote>/*
O 2004-08-18 19:50 +0000 andysan         xmltv                                  =xmltv=                                  <remote>/*
O 2012-11-28 06:23 +0000 anonymous                                              =.=                                      <remote>/*
O 2012-04-19 02:03 +0000 anonymous       [2003.04.04.20.57.50] libxmltv                               =083=                                    <remote>/*
...
```

but this definitely isn't sorted by date (descending - I want to see latest first), and there are no log messages either.

Is there a way to obtain a one-line-per-commit-with-message type of log from `cvs`, similar to what `git log` and `svn log` do?